# How can I enable Cognito 'User name' login using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a new AWS Cognito user pool using Terraform, and I can't choose the user name sign-in option:[this is my code]

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool" {
  name                = "User_Pool_demo"
  username_attributes = ["username"]

  username_configuration {
    case_sensitive = false
  }

  schema {
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    mutable             = true
    name                = "username"
    required            = true
    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = 1
      max_length = 2048
     }
   }
 }
```

[This is the error I'm getting]

> **Error: expected username_attributes.0 to be one of [phone_number email], got username**
>   with aws_cognito_user_pool.pool,
>   on cognito_userpool.tf line 4, in resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool":
>    4:   username_attributes = ["username"]

When I try to create it through the console, I do see that there is the option to use a username
[image of an elaborate form rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsyyi.png)

Comment: Will you please write down code as text, instead of image.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the last one AWS terraform provider [version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool), `username_attributes` argument support only email addresses or phone numbers:

> username_attributes - (Optional) Whether email addresses or phone numbers can be specified as usernames when a user signs up.

That means you can't use user name in that configuration.
I believe the best what you can do that create the issue in [terraform-provider-aws](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues) GitHub project with "Enhancement" label and ask to add support for that field.